# WPF DatePicker show DateTime.Today OR Binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datepicker

What is the best way to have a WPF `DatePicker` show a predefined `DateTime` (e.g. `DateTime.Today`) while still maintaining binding?

`SelectedDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Today}"`

and

`Text="{Binding Path=MyPublicProperty.ADateTimeMemberProperty, Mode=TwoWay}"`

don't play well together. When a `UserControl` is loaded, I'd like it to display today's date, until a row is selected. Is there a way to make them get along?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Text="{Binding Path=MyPublicProperty.ADateTimeMemberProperty, 
       Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue={x:Static sys:DateTime.Today}}"
```

Use FallbackValue to set a value when it cannot be retrieved from the binding.